# How to trigger an event when right clicking on the unoccupied area of a QTableView

Tags: python, pyqt

I have an application made basically of a `QTableView`. I would like to display a contextual menu when right clicking on the unoccupied area of the table view. `QTableWidget` has a `itemAt` method that could do the trick but unfortunately, to fill my purposes, I must use a `QTableView` which lacks this method. I also tried with an event filter but without success. Would you know to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the [`indexAt()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.15/qtableview.html#indexAt) method and verify that [`QModelIndex`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.15/qmodelindex.html) is not valid:

```py
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMenu, QTableView


class TableView(QTableView):
    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        super().contextMenuEvent(event)
        ix = self.indexAt(event.pos())
        if not ix.isValid():
            menu = QMenu()
            menu.addAction("foo")
            menu.addAction("bar")
            menu.addAction("baz")
            menu.exec_(event.globalPos())


def main():
    app = QApplication([])

    view = TableView()
    view.resize(640, 480)
    view.show()

    model = QStandardItemModel(4, 5)
    view.setModel(model)

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I could finally find a way to do this by doing:

```py
def mousePressEvent(self, event):

    if self.model() is None:
        return

    if self.rowAt(event.pos().y()) == -1:
        self.onShowContextualMenu(event.pos())

    return super(FileSystemTableView, self).mousePressEvent(event)
```